# Returning multiple values from a function in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I researched and tried but cant figure it out this is what i got so far.
What i want it to do is concatenate Fstring and Lstring and return the result plus the current date in this case @date
i declared the variables @Fstring and @Lstring as input and @date as the getdate function.
I can only get it to either return the date or @fullname :(
and i cant figure out where im wrong
any help in the right direction will be appreciated

```
==== start function===
create function ufn_function_4
(
        @Fstring varchar(20) , @Lstring varchar(20)
)
returns varchar (20)
as
begin
Declare @date datetime = getdate()
Declare @fullname varchar(100)
set @fullname = @Fstring + ' ' + @Lstring;
return (@date+@fullname)
end
go

==== start select ====

select [dbo].[ufn_function_4]('Fred','Van Vliet');
```

Comment: Have you considered writing a Stored Procedure with one or more OUT parameters instead of using a function?

Answer (score 0):

Change this line as you have just one `VARCHAR(20)` as `RETURN`

```
SET @fullname = @Fstring + ' ' + @Lstring + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @date)
```

If you want to return both in separate values you need to define a Table-Valued function

Something like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ufn_function_4
(   
    @Fstring varchar(20) , @Lstring varchar(20)
)
RETURNS @table TABLE ([date] DATETIME, fullname VARCHAR(1000)) 
AS
BEGIN

    Declare @date datetime = getdate()
    Declare @fullname varchar(100)
    set @fullname = @Fstring + ' ' + @Lstring;

    INSERT INTO @table
        SELECT @date, @fullname

    RETURN
END
```

To call function

```
SELECT * FROM ufn_function_4('james', 'connery')
```

Answer (score -1):

the function you created is a **Scalar function** which you did it almost right except:

**1.** increase the length of return type unless your function will return a string of maximum length of 20

**2:** cast the date time to varchar when you want to concatinate it with varchar values unless you will get type casting error

**3:** remove the semicolon after setting @file name

I mean *your function:*

```
create function ufn_function_4
(
        @Fstring varchar(20) , @Lstring varchar(20)
)
returns varchar (100)
as
begin
Declare @date datetime = getdate()
Declare @fullname varchar(100)
set @fullname = @Fstring + ' ' + @Lstring
return (cast(@date as varchar(20))+@fullname)
end
```

*execution:*

```
select [dbo].[ufn_function_4]('Fred','Van Vliet');
```

*output:*

```
Apr 2 2015 4:36AMFred Van Vliet
```

**But** if you want to return `multiple` `records` or `fields` then use **table-valued** function in this case you need to just `change the return type` to be a table:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ufn_function_4
(   
    @Fstring varchar(20) , @Lstring varchar(20)
)
RETURNS @table TABLE ([date] DATETIME, fullname VARCHAR(100)) 
AS
BEGIN

    Declare @date datetime = getdate()
    Declare @fullname varchar(100)
    set @fullname = @Fstring + ' ' + @Lstring

    INSERT INTO @table
        SELECT @date, @fullname

    RETURN
```

and *run* it like:

```
SELECT * FROM ufn_function_4('Fred','Van Vliet')
```

*output:*

```
date                         fullname
April, 02 2015 05:11:38      Fred Van Vliet
```